# kendo ui angular 2 tree doesn't get updated after item is removed

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

the following scenario: i have a kendo ui tree which i dynamically add and remove children of it.

Adding item works fine, but when i remove a child the tree doesn't get refreshed.

I already checked that the children length is decreased.

Can you please check this plunkr out: http://plnkr.co/edit/XYc5Zz?p=preview

I tried this, but it doesn't work.

```
removeItem()
{
  let nodeRef = this.getNodeRef(false);
  alert(nodeRef.items.length);
  nodeRef.items = nodeRef.items.filter(item=> item !== this.selectedItem);
  alert(nodeRef.items.length);
  this.changeDetectionRef.detectChanges();
}
```

I hope you can help me with this. Of course you can tell me other ways to dynamically modified the kendo tree.

Best regards

Comment: Have a look at this, maybe here you'll find a hint: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17827453/kendo-ui-reload-treeview/22478002

Comment: Thank you DiabolicWords, but the link you sent me is about kendo tree for jquery. I need a solution for kendo tree for angular 2.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are replacing the original array with a new one, and *kendo-treeview* is still referring to the previous array.
Try this to remove an element from the array:

```
const found = nodeRef.items.find(item => item === this.selectedItem);
nodeRef.items.splice(nodeRef.items.indexOf(found), 1);
```

I hope it helps and that it's not too late.